# Generic Debug/Release Tag in csproj File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, stylecop, csproj

Our project uses StyleCop to enforce coding standards.  Our goal is to treat all StyleCop warnings as errors.  However we only want to enforce this on Release Builds.  Since code is constantly in flux until a developer gets ready to perform a check-in, we don't want StyleCop errors complaining about segments of code that may not even make it into source control.

Currently we have to do this in our csproj files:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>true</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
  <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>true</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
  <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Currently I have to set `StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings` on every configuration combination.  Is there a generic Release and Debug tag that I can use to set `StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings` to `true` on all debug builds and `false` on all release builds instead of individually?

Comment: Sure, it is $(Configuration).  Just remove |$(Platform) from your test.

Comment: I feel like an idiot.  That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by Hans Passant, the solution is to add the following `PropertyGroup` tags.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>true</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
  <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
</PropertyGroup>
```